# A question about double integral!

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics

$$Q(C) = \iint_C (x^2+y^2) dxdy$$

where

$$C = \{(x,y): -1\le x=y\le1\}$$

I am struggling with this problem for about 3hours.

but I can't solve this one.

how can I handle the $x=y$ in the domain?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The integral vanishes as the integration domain has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: you mean that the result of integral is zero right?

Comment: Please clarify- Can your domain also be written?
$-1 \leq x$ and $  x=y $ and $ y \leq 1$

Comment: Yes, I think so. I literally took the problem from 'Introduction to mathematical statistics' by Hogg.

Comment: @Rooster The answer given by Hogg to that part of problem 1.2.10.  is $0$; because $C_2:=\{(x,y): -1\leq x=y\leq 1\}$ is a *line segment* and so has zero area.

Comment: As Federico and GrahamKemp have already mentioned, the integral vanishes for regular functions (e.g. it may not vanish for functions that come up with a Dirac's delta on the line segment). To observe this by yourself, since the integrand is non-negative, consider evaluating the integral over $D_e$, where $$D_e=\{(x,y):-1<x<1,-1<y<1,|y-x|<e\}.$$Then, tend $e\to 0$ and see what happens (this is analogous to what is done in measure theory).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** for the area of integration $C$:

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain why area of C looks like that?

Comment: Or is it different area of integration C from area of C?

Comment: To @Rooster: Your integral have sense only for some two-dimensional set $C \subseteq \mathbb{R^2}$. For set $C$ I would personally use: $C=\{(x,y):-1\le x\le y, x \le y \le 1\}$.

Comment: To @Anton Vrdoljak: First, thanks for your explanation! However, I can't fully understand what you just replied. Is it okay to understand that my $C$ is not well-defined?

Comment: To @Rooster: It is OK.

Comment: To #Anton Vrdoljak: Thanks very much! I appreciate your help.